# Is it illegal to transmit in the FM range for personal use

Tags: frequency-modulation, licensing

I am building an FM transmitter. It is going to be designed to transmit only for a short range of around 50 to 100 meters. My question is whether it is illegal to transmit signals in the FM band over this short range without owning a license? If yes, what should I do to test it?

P.S. I live in India.

Comment: dunno about India, but in the U.S., you can get away with it if the transmitter is less than 100 mW.  the signal will not get far, probably less than 200 meters.

Comment: Try the Telecom Regulatory Authority of India **[here.](http://www.trai.gov.in/)**

Comment: I can't get 40 feet / 9 meters on a commercial fcc authorized personal fm transmitter in the us. Let alone double or triple digit meters.

Comment: I don't get you. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Passerby, you're probably right.  long ago i had a walkie-talkie that was about 30 Mhz and 100 mW (but it was AM, not FM, but that should matter less, IMO) and we could get it to work for about 1/8 mile.

Comment: I'm saying is that personal, non commercial FM transmitter are highly limited in range. It's hard to get a good signal outside of 10 meters without modding or getting license required equipment. And since every country follows US and UK standards for radio, it's most likely the same for India.

Comment: well, they certainly have changed the FCC rules, since i was a kid with a walkie-talkie.  in the 1970s, they were just changing from transmitter input power to "effective radiated power".  both limits were expressed in watts, not in field strength.  i presume one can take your 150 μV/m and turn that into intensity (W/m²) and then add up all the m² of a sphere with radius 3m and get *effective radiated power* from that.  otherwise, i dunno how to compare.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Actually, according to Part 15 of the FCC Rules and Regulations, [**CFR47,**](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=28ec52ccd86863c4e3053d95f5b57808&mc=true&node=pt47.1.15&rgn=div5) the limit is a field strength of 250 microvolts per meter at a range of 3 meters, in a band 200 kHz wide from 88 to 216MHz.

Comment: @EMFields, knowing the characteristic impedance of free space, what is the formula for converting field strength in V/m to intensity in W/m²?  i can fiddle around with it (just messing with dimensional analysis) but i don't have my old fields book handy.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: [**Check this out**](http://www.semtech.com/images/promo/Semtech_ACS_Rad_Pwr_Field_Strength.pdf)

Comment: Shouldn't this heavily depend on frequency? For example, in Germany, 100mW is the limit for private wireless networks, but a private radio station (e.g. fm transmitter for car radio) is limited to 50nW. (Yes, nanowatt)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson 100 mW can get many, many miles. This is bad advice you are giving when you say "less than 200m". It may be based on experience BUT the receiver might have been poorly designed with not much gain and did you have a quarter wave dipole receive antenna (2.5m long)?

Comment: @robertbristow-Johnson, as above - 100mW will get you around the world at HF, and low VHF, at sunspot maxima

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different locations will have different rules. If you live in India, check the regulations for India.

Generally, powerful transmissions in licensed bands like FM audio must be licensed, to prevent interference with other users. If other users complain, you may get tracked down, and your equipment confiscated or destroyed.

Most places have unlicensed bands as well, like the so called ISM frequencies, and usually a few other bands for other purposes as well, like garage door openers and short range personal comms.

If your transmitter is very low power, and operated at times and at frequencies when it could not interfere with any stations your neighbours in range are tuned to, then you can probably figure out what the actual chances of causing trouble or getting caught are.